# Having an issue with generating a new set of URLs to fetch in Nutch

Tags: nutch

Having an issue with generating a new set of URLs to fetch in Nutch.

Here is the command that I am using:

```
# $NUTCH_HOME/runtime/local/bin/nutch generate -topN 10
```

Result:

```
Generator: starting at 2016-12-14 19:16:50
Generator: Selecting best-scoring urls due for fetch.
Generator: filtering: true
Generator: normalizing: true
Generator: running in local mode, generating exactly one partition.
Generator: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/root/bob/-topN/current
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:287)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:229)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileInputFormat.listStatus(SequenceFileInputFormat.java:45)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:315)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeOldSplits(JobSubmitter.java:329)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.java:320)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:196)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1290)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1287)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1287)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:575)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:570)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:570)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:561)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:862)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Generator.generate(Generator.java:589)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Generator.run(Generator.java:764)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Generator.main(Generator.java:717)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missing parameters in your command, take a look at https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/bin/nutch%20generate basically you need to supply the path of your crawldb and segment subdirectories.

Comment: Is it normal that I had to not only create `crawldb/` dir and `segment1/` dir, but inside of them I had to create  `crawldb/current/` and `segment1/crawl_generate`?

Comment: I made the mistake because I was following this documentation: https://gist.github.com/xrstf/b48a970098a8e76943b9

Comment: So you're using the 2.x branch of Nutch right? Any particular reason why you're not using the `bin/crawl` script that handles all the steps for you?

Comment: When I do `$NUTCH_HOME/runtime/local/bin/nutch` I get nutch 1.12. But I was sure I was using version 2. Strange. But I do see `bin/crawl`.

Comment: Well like I said I was following the instruction here: https://gist.github.com/xrstf/b48a970098a8e76943b9 Because I am trying to send my crawls results to ElasticSearch. I am using Accumulo has the DB. But when I look into Accumulo it is still empty. To be honest I am trying to wrap my head around Nutch. I am slowly getting a understanding of how it works but I am still confused.